# Jest mocking react navigation stack

Tags: react-native, unit-testing, ts-jest, react-native-web

I am trying to mock Stack navigation using this code

```
jest.mock('@react-navigation/stack', () => ({
  require('@react-navigation/stack/lib/commonjs')
}));
```

but I am getting this error

```
 FAIL  __tests__/App-test.tsx
  ● Test suite failed to run

    TypeError: (0 , stack_1.createStackNavigator) is not a function

      27 |
    > 28 | const Stack = createStackNavigator();
         |                                   ^
```

which means it did not detect `createStackNavigator` as function from the commonjs

even if I mock it with a dummy function, let us say `jest.fn()` still the TSX code won't work

```
<Stack.Navigator>
   <Stack.Screen
      initialParams={props.route.params}
      name={"My Menu"}
      component={MyComponent}
```

so I how do I properly mock all of the sub component `Navigator` `Screen` `component` ? and make the jest test renderer to properly work